# Swift error unwrapping nil from Nib in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift

Getting some weird results, I am loading a nib file that I created as a custom alert view. However it is failing in the viewDidLoad method when it tries to change the text of the UILabel that is in the custom alert view. (gets unwrapping nil error)

When I go to the nib file all of my outlets are connected (shows the highlighted dots next to them). The file's owner is also set to the correct class name.

However when the code fails and pulls up the debugger all of the outlets are empty. This code is occurring in viewDidAppear so shouldn't the outlets and all of the UI be loaded at that point?

**Side information:**
The other weird part, is that I am testing this on two different devices. One is running iOS 8.4 and the other is running iOS 9.1(beta). The iOS 9.1 device functions normally and does not ever throw this nil error. The iOS 8.4 device is the one that throws the error. Running Xcode 6.4 swift 1.2. In order to get the code to run on my iOS 9.1 I open Xcode 7 with my device connected to the computer then close out and reopen Xcode 6.4 and it allows me to set my target iOS to 9.1.

**Update**

Image of where code is failing
[image]

**Nib file view controller:**

```
@IBOutlet var messageLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var notificationHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var notificationWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var singleButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var rightButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var leftButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var middleButtonSpacerView: UIView!

var buttonDelegate: NotificationButtonDelegate?
var grayView: UIView!
var buttonTitles = [String]()
var notificationWidth: CGFloat!
var notificationHeight: CGFloat = 200.0
var hideProgressView = false
var hideNotificationView = false
var currentProgress: CGFloat = 0.0
var messageLabelText = ""


required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    messageLabel.text = messageLabelText

    if buttonTitles.count > 0 {
        if buttonTitles.count == 1 {
            rightButton.hidden = true
            leftButton.hidden = true
            middleButtonSpacerView.hidden = true
            singleButton.setTitle("\(buttonTitles[0])", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        } else {
            leftButton.setTitle("\(buttonTitles[0])", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            rightButton.setTitle("\(buttonTitles[1])", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    }


    if self.hideProgressView {
        self.progressView.hidden = true
        if messageLabel.bounds.height >= 90 {
            notificationHeightConstraint.constant = 225
        } else {
            notificationHeightConstraint.constant = 200.0
        }
    }

    if self.hideNotificationView {
        self.notificationView.hidden = true
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        notificationHeightConstraint.constant = 160
    }

    self.notificationWidthConstraint.constant = notificationWidth
    self.view.needsUpdateConstraints()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
```

**Custom Alert View class initialization in main view controller**

```
var notificationPopup: NotificationPopupViewController!
var progressPopup: NotificationPopupViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hasError = false
    notificationPopup = NotificationPopupViewController()
    progressPopup = NotificationPopupViewController()
```

**Call in main viewController to present the custom alert view**

```
@IBAction func configureSystemButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    var prefs: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var hostedSSID = prefs.valueForKey("HostedSSID") as? String
    var currentSSID = sureVue.getUserSSID()

    if currentSSID != hostedSSID || currentSSID == "" {
        self.notificationPopup.showInView(self.view, withMessage: "You are not connected to the device's wifi.\nFollow instructions on launch page to connect.", animated: false, buttonLabels: ["Ok"])
```

**method in nib viewController that sets up the custom alert view**

```
    func showInView(aView: UIView!, withMessage message: String!, animated: Bool, buttonLabels:[String]) {
    self.hideNotificationView = false
    self.hideProgressView = true
    self.buttonTitles = buttonLabels
    notificationWidth = aView.bounds.width * 0.925
    grayView = UIView(frame: aView.frame)
    grayView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 170/255.0, green: 170/255.0, blue: 170/255.0, alpha: 0.75)
    grayView.center = CGPoint(x: aView.bounds.width/2, y: aView.bounds.height/2)
    grayView.addSubview(self.view)
    self.view.center = CGPoint(x: aView.bounds.width/2, y: aView.bounds.height/2)
    aView.addSubview(grayView)
    messageLabelText = message


    if animated
    {
        self.showAnimate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post some code, maybe just around the `viewDidLoad` area, also.. Where is the text that you are trying to set on the label coming from? - are you able to use stack trace to find out exactly where the nil value is?

Comment: @Wezly just updated with some images of code

Comment: Don't post images of code. Copy and paste the text of the relevant code and put that in your question.

Comment: @rmaddy will do, but just curious, what is wrong with images exactly?

Comment: Images are too hard to read and people can't copy and paste code from the images when posting answers.

Comment: I'm not sure why the weak reference in this instance would mean the label gets deallocated, however, maybe try a stronger reference to your label `@IBOutlet var messageLabel: UILabel!`

Comment: @Wezly Yea I just noticed that I think I made a mistake when connecting the outlet, however even if I comment out that line "messageLabel.text = messageLabelText", it fails at the next UI change "rightButton.hidden = true"... Also just changed it to a strong outlet and got the same error

Comment: How is self.notificationPopup initialised?

Comment: @pbasdf just added it thanks!

Comment: I think that's the problem: you need to use init(nibName: ...), rather than `notificationPopup = NotificationPopupViewController()` in order to get the instance to load from the nib and set its outlets.

Comment: @pbasdf ill try that now, is this something that has changed with iOS 9.0+ because I don't get this nil error on my iOS 9.1 device, it behaves properly.

Comment: Don't hold me to it, but i think they've changed the default nibName that is used if you don't specify one.

Comment: See the notes under UIKit in the [iOS9 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-9.0/)

Comment: @pbasdf it worked! if you want to make that an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Thanks.  Incidentally, are your popup buttons working?  I would have expected you need to use `addChildViewController` and `didMoveToParentViewController` to get them to work.

Comment: @pbasdf they are working, I have delegate methods that I call in my nib viewcontroller and hook into them in my main view controller. I have also used self.notificationPopup.rightButton.addTarget in my main VC, after I do the showInView call and it works as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, I think the problem is in the way self.notificationPopup is initialised. You need to use `init(nibName: ...)`, rather than `notificationPopup = NotificationPopupViewController()` in order to get the instance to load from the nib and set its outlets.

The existing code works OK in iOS 9 because Apple have changed the default nibNames that are used if you do not specify one when initialising a UIViewController.  See the notes under UIKit in the [iOS9 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-9.0/).

Comment: So what I changed was
    notificationPopup = NotifcationPopupViewController()
to
    notificationPopup = NotificationPopupViewController(nibName:"NotificationPopupViewController",bundle:nil)

So the name of my nib file was NotificationPopupViewController.xib... probably should change that so its not the same as the class name but just wanted to clarify for anyone who might be reading this later that you will obviously use the nib file name.

Comment: @shreddish I think .swift and .xib having the same name is OK - it's what Xcode does if you tick "also create xib" when creating a new file.

Comment: That's true. Ironically I created my xib file and then my swift file separately so I was thinking that it could be possible that you have two different names, but yes if you tick "also create xib" they will have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

In case `init(nibName: ...)` was used correctly, try to -

1. Clean / rebuild the project
2. Delete the app from simulator / device

Sometimes when adding new files Xcode 7 builds the app incorrectly.